# Getting invalid opcode: PUSH0 on ARB and not on BSC for the same contracts interactions

Tags: safe-core

I deployed 2 proxied contracts on BSC and ARB. The admin of this contracts are Safe wallets.  When i execute transactions on BSC everything works as expected, on ARB it fails with the error: invalid opcode: PUSH0.
If i try to run the same function with a regular wallet as admin it works, this problem only happens when i try to execute the contract with the safe.
The contracts are deployed both with Paris EvmVersion and Solidity v0.8.23+commit.f704f362

Any clue about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Lower the solidity version, but try v0.8.18.

Answer (score 0):

Dev Advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here

The issue with the `invalid opcode: PUSH0` error is related to EVM (Ethereum Virtual Machine) compatibility and specific opcode support across different blockchain environments.

### Background on `PUSH0`:

The `PUSH0` opcode was introduced in Solidity 0.8.20 as part of EIP-3855. Its primary purpose is to efficiently push the constant value 0 onto the stack, which was previously more cumbersome and less gas-efficient. This opcode brings several benefits, including reduced bytecode size and gas costs for operations requiring a zero value on the stack.

### EVM Compatibility:

The core of the problem likely stems from the EVM compatibility layer of the specific blockchain you're working with. While Binance Smart Chain (BSC) and Arbitrum (ARB) aim to be EVM-compatible, there can be differences in the implementation and the version of the EVM they are compatible with at any given time.

You mentioned using Solidity v0.8.23. Since `PUSH0` is included from Solidity 0.8.20 onwards, your contracts will use this opcode.

### Potential Solutions:

- **Verify EVM Compatibility**: Make sure your node is running the latest version; according to the [Arbitrum docs](https://docs.arbitrum.io/for-devs/concepts/differences-between-arbitrum-ethereum/solidity-support#differences-from-solidity-on-ethereum), the push0 opcode should be supported.
- **Use solidity 0.8.19**: If your node does not support the updated version, deploy the contracts using a Solidity version that does not use the push0 opcode. Any version from 0.8.19 and below should work.

[Chainstack](https://console.chainstack.com/) nodes are updated to ArbOS 11 if you need a compatible node!